# How to write an analogue of returning text

Tags: java, php, aes

I don't understand how to do this in Java:

```
$text = "YOU IN";
// get the password key via: `base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32)) = gGwdF6FDd68C/ANEqlqgOrsLqqC11u2JYn7NEJP10DA` = and further:
$keyPass = base64_decode("gGwdF6FDd68C/ANEqlqgOrsLqqC11u2JYn7NEJP10DA=");
$rndBytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc')); // 0PLpHMRYGwDBgcBsbeI3Qw==
$encText = openssl_encrypt($text, 'aes-256-cbc', $keyPass, 0, $rndBytes); // n+hHeLU4eI9r23ckxOwBOA==
```

So that you can also return this text without any problems:

```
echo openssl_decrypt(
    base64_decode("n+hHeLU4eI9r23ckxOwBOA=="),
    'aes-256-cbc',
    base64_decode("gGwdF6FDd68C/ANEqlqgOrsLqqC11u2JYn7NEJP10DA="),
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    base64_decode("0PLpHMRYGwDBgcBsbeI3Qw==")
); // YOU IN
```

How can I do this in Java?

The task in Java is to return, not to encrypt.
That is, the resulting `$encText` will always be different, while any one will fit `openssl_decrypt`.

Tried to do like this:

```
final Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
final byte[] encBytes = decoder.decode("n+hHeLU4eI9r23ckxOwBOA=="),
             keyPass = decoder.decode("gGwdF6FDd68C/ANEqlqgOrsLqqC11u2JYn7NEJP10DA="),
             rndBytes = decoder.decode("0PLpHMRYGwDBgcBsbeI3Qw==");
final String algo = "AES";
final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyPass, algo);
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algo);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
final byte[] decBytes = cipher.doFinal(encBytes);
System.out.println(new String(decBytes));
//
// Return hieroglyphs:
//
// ��*�#в��\��i�9���:�_�`�-U��
```

I don't know how to find this `aes-256-cbc`...
If you try to change the line:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(rndBytes));
```

Crashes with an error:
`InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: ECB mode cannot use IV`

Comment: If you want to decrypt, you must specify the decryption mode and IV: `cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(rndBytes))`. Mode of operation and padding must also be defined: `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")`. Also it is more robust to specify the encoding in `new String()`.

Comment: please don't delete and repost a question - instead edit the previous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331270/return-text-from-cipher to make it answerable

Comment: @kleopatra, Of course I understand everything, but wait for hours until someone opens the topic. I don't really want to. There was a problem here, I messed everything up, in fact, `SecretKeySpec` needed `AES`, and Cipther needed `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`, and I didn’t understand why there was `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE` when needed `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE`, copied the wrong line by mistake.

Comment: _but wait for hours until someone opens the topic. I don't really want to_ what do you expect? This is not a service site - if you are in a hurry, consider hiring a consultant ;) Actually, this site is a community effort to build a useful knowledge base, its focus is on being helpful to __future__ readers with a similar problem as yours. Which implies you as part of builder/collector

Comment: @kleopatra, Time is money, you want to wait, I'm not going to wait for anything. I didn't break anything. The closed question also said, or create a new one. Created. More questions?

Comment: Beware: every deleted question is a step into a question ban. If you disagree with the site rules, please discuss them on meta. Anyway, your options: a) follow the site rules b) go elsewhere ..

Comment: @kleopatra, Well, then you need to write it right after closing, and not abroad or after, when they already ban you. And sending everyone to another place is such an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hurrah! Understood! Thanx @Topaco.

```
final Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
final byte[] encBytes = decoder.decode("n+hHeLU4eI9r23ckxOwBOA=="),
             keyPass = decoder.decode("gGwdF6FDd68C/ANEqlqgOrsLqqC11u2JYn7NEJP10DA="),
             rndBytes = decoder.decode("0PLpHMRYGwDBgcBsbeI3Qw==");
final String algo = "AES";
final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyPass, algo);
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(rndBytes));
final byte[] decBytes = cipher.doFinal(encBytes);
System.out.println(new String(decBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); // YOU IN
```